# Git default branch issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, github

I'm new to git and I'm working with another developer. I want whenever I do `git pull` or `git push` to only affect the development branch. I went to .git/config but I don't understand what is there. Any pointers would be much appreciated.

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = true
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
[remote "origin"]
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
    url = https://github.com/Zeasdfasdf4/m2ex2
[branch "master"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/master
[branch "development"]
    remote = origin
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't switch branches with your gitconfig. How can do this, however, with the `git checkout` command.

Simply run `git checkout development` to switch to this branch. This also means that pulls and pushes will interact with the remote development branch (instead of the remote master branch).

Comment: You may also want to change your `push.default` (which is a gitconfig item) to `current`, `upstream`, or `simple`.  See the section on `push.default` in the git-config documentation.  This feature is relatively new, some old versions of git may lack it.